# jQuery Keyup Doesn't work more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

SO i tried moving the script from head to body.But doesn't help.

i am making a search box and the function holds good ony for one search. after that it doesnt update the values for some reason.

Heres the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchquery").on('keyup change', function(){
    var username = $("#searchquery").val()
    if (username.length > 0){
        $.post("functions/searchuser.php", {username: username},
        function(result){
            $("ul").empty();
            $("ul").show();
            if(result == 'nf'){
                 $("#srchview").show();
                 $("ul").html("No Such user exists");
                 }
            else{

                 var obj = JSON.parse(result);  
                 $.each(obj, function(key, val) {           // iterate over result
                 console.log(val.username);
                 $("ul").append("<a href=/"+val.username+"><li>"+val.fname+" "+val.lname+"<br>@"+val.username+"</li></a>");
                 })
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => person[key]=null);
      }    
    });
    }
    else{
        $("#srchview").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Not the problem, but why are you adding non-li content directly to a ul element?

Comment: The ul has been made in html, i am appening the li to be displayed below the search box. But what is a non-li content ? I can define the content i want in li.

Comment: `$("ul").html("No Such user exists")` appends text directly to the ul. In your loop you are appending `<a>` elements directly to the ul. Neither is valid HTML. Anyway, is there other code on your page? Where is the `person` variable declared?

Comment: A `<ul>` element's **only** [**valid children**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) are `<li>` elements (well, in addition to the script-supporting elements `<script>` and `<template>`).

Comment: Yes. I made a big mistake there... i ll just correct that and recheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it . the fourth last line that hid my searchview in the else clause

```
$("#srchview").hide();
```

i just had to do this in the if clause.

```
$("#srchview").show();
```